# display result of field using *** at first 3 characters when condition is met in sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that look like this :

```
Username   |   Status
aaa        |   Pending
bbbbbbb    |   Pending
cccc       |   Cancelled
dddddddd   |   Cancelled
eeeeee     |   Approved
ffffff     |   Approved
```

the result that I'd like to show at the end is like this :

```
Status    | Username
Pending   | ***aaa, ***bbbb
Cancelled | ***cccc, ***ddddd 
Approved  | ***eee, ***fff
```

I've tried to do this select query

```
SELECT distinct status,CASE WHEN LENGTH(username) >=6 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(replace(username, left( username, 3 ) , '***') SEPARATOR ', ') ELSE GROUP_CONCAT('***',username SEPARATOR ', ') END AS Username FROM table group by status
```

However, the result of `bbbbbbb` from my query won't work because there is 3 characters username at first row. so, the result become like this :

```
Status    | Username
Pending   | ***aaa, ***bbbbbbb       // wrong (it should be ***aaa , ***bbbb)
Cancelled | ***cccc, ***ddddd // true
Approved  | ***eee, ***fff   // true
```

How do I perform the query to show the result that I expected?. thank you before

Comment: What result you get with `(username) >=3` ?

Comment: `aaa` will show  `***` only if i make condition `length(username)>=3`, i would like to display `***aaa` @Rishi

Comment: I think you want to hide full username , if username is `aaa` why you want to display `***aaa` , it showing complete username,  you can display also display like ` ******` ?

Comment: because the username's character is not qualified to the condition, so i want to show the full username with `***` for privacy and security and if i just display `***` only, the owner of that username wouldn't know their username and status.. @Rishi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you need to move `CASE` inside `GROUP_CONCAT`. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT status,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CASE
      WHEN LENGTH(username) >= 6 THEN REPLACE(username, LEFT(username, 3), '***')
      ELSE CONCAT('***', username)
    END SEPARATOR ', '
  )AS Username
FROM table
GROUP BY status
```

Comment: yeahhh!!!! finally.... i never thought that I can put `CASE` inside `GROUP_CONCAT`.. thanks man!